# How to return stack Trace to Client in MULE..?

Tags: exception, browser, stack-trace, mule

Does anybody know how to print ***full stack trace*** on the Browser, when a Runtime Exception occurs in MULE..??

When a runtime Exception occurs, MULE throws  a 500 Server Error to the client , but shows no details to the client. It prints the whole stack trace in Console or Log Files (like the following) :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3677)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2749)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:494)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' 
    for everything)
```

Can i show the same stack Trace on the Browser (to the client)..??

And if possible , then also tell me how to switch ON or OFF printing of Stack Trace on Browser..??

(*It may be possible that sometime in future , i dont want to show stack trace on browser*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  I assume you are using a regular HTTP endpoint and this is a REST type service(?) If so, you can simply put a try/catch around the code causing the exception and return whatever text you want.

There are also exception strategies (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Error+Handling) for doing more sophisticated error handling, but it sounds like you are looking for the simple answer above.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more info about your mule config and the service that is raising the exception.

Comment: Obviously i have implemented Try / Catch in the whole of my Project..!!..n i am returning the exception in whatever form i want..But what i was asking was : Suppose you put a "\" character in URL , then MULE returns a 500 Server Error (Obviously it should , coz it is a URI exception). But can i catch that exception as well (Somewhere in mule_config file)..??

Comment: Does that mean you have tried an exception strategy as well and that did not help?

Comment: yeah..i have tried an custom-exception-strategy, but the class it calls can only return a Mule-Message , and not what i want. (a StackTrace OR something other that this)..!!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box in Mule to do that. You have to implement an exception handler that will format the stacktrace in the Message exception payload and return it to the caller.

In your case, the HTTP transport has a particularity that can be found in the HttpMessageReceiver code:

```
try
{
    conn.writeResponse(processRequest(request));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
...
    conn.writeResponse(buildFailureResponse(request.getRequestLine().getHttpVersion(), httpStatus, e.getMessage()));
```

This means that when an exception crops-up to the top level, the creation of the failure message response is not customizable: you get this pretty technical message back and that is all.

I see two options to solve your problem:

- sub-class HttpMessageReceiver and make the response message customizable in your version,
- drop the HTTP transport in favor of the Jetty one (look at the bookstore example) and customize the response error messages at the web container level.

Comment: I am never throwing an Exception from my JAVA class. Every exception in all my java classes have been catch-ed. But what if there is an Exception generated by MULE itself like "URL Exception". (I have explained the situation in my other comment below.). How can i catch that Exception as well..??